# Keycloak angular 2

Tags: angular, keycloak

I'm trying out keycloak with angular 2. I'm making a service where I do as they do in their doc. However it always returns `not authenticated` even though I'm connected when I connect to my account keycloak url (`auth/realms/wb/account`).

```
declare var Keycloak: any;

@Injectable()
export class UserMockService {

    constructor() {
        let keycloak: any = new Keycloak('assets/keycloak.json');

         keycloak.init().success(function(authenticated) {
            alert(authenticated ? 'authenticated' : 'not authenticated');
        }).error(function() {
            alert('failed to initialize');
        });
     }
}
```

Yes it does find the json.

```
{
  "realm": "wb",
  "auth-server-url": "http://192.168.99.100/auth",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "wb",
  "public-client": true
}
```

Oh yeah and before I forget: what the heck is the URL to redirect user to connect to my app ? Seems like it should be something easy to find but their doc is so scattered.. To connect at the moment I use /auth/realms/wb/account but that's the url to connect to the account settings..

So the flow is like this :

- user goes to http://192.168.99.100
- user clicks login buttons
- user is redirected to the login URL, at the moment I use `http://192.168.99.100/auth/realms/wb/account`.
- user comes back on the app and the angular service tells me if the user is logged in.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can recommend having a look into the official [*Angular 2* client app example](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/fc6d6ff7f7dae7fb25edf052659d18cd8de55a5f/examples/demo-template/angular2-product-app) on the *Keycloak* GitHub.

A month ago, I successfully created a Keycloak secured Angular 2 app using the snippets out of this example.

Comment: I find this blog post a little more verbose: http://paulbakker.io/java/jwt-keycloak-angular2/